# How to use a prefix index for an index-only scan in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, prefix, composite-key

Imagine I have a (huge) table like so:

```
category   type  
--------   ----
foo        EC22
foo        EC00
bar        EC00
bar        EDC0
...        ...
```

The first two characters in `type` have a special meaning and I'm only interested in those for `SELECT` purposes. I want to use a composite index with a prefix on `type` like so: `category, type(2)`

Now when I do:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT category, type FROM table
WHERE category = 'foo'
AND LEFT(type,2) = 'EC'
```

... it tells me MySQL is `Using index condition;` (meaning rows are read to doublecheck the index).

I want to use everything that has an index value of `EC` and continue with the rest of my index-only scan. E.g. `EXPLAIN` telling me `Using index;` (without `condition`). There is no need to double check the actual value of this field, because I'm only looking at the first two characters. Is it possible to achieve or force this?

#### Update

I can `SET optimizer_switch='index_condition_pushdown=off';` and then `EXPLAIN` changes from `Using index lookup;` to `Using where;` and it's about 15% faster. I guess I'm not entirely sure what's going on here and how I can see my query is done using indices alone.

Comment: Is there any chance you can split the `type` column into two columns, `type_prefix` and `type_suffix`?

Comment: Indexes for `char` columns are B-trees, so you shouldn't need to do anything special to use a prefix as the index.

Comment: @Bamar I would love to change the table in multiple ways, but I am only allowed to create indices. With billions of records, I guess it would lock the database for too long (production server). I'd just like to be able to do my query without doing table lookups. Theoretically it should be possible, but technically I don't know.

Comment: The index on `(category,type(2))` is not a covering index for the query, because of `type` column in the SELECT list. So MySQL has to visit the row in the table in order to retrieve the whole column (to return). With that query, and a non-covering index, MySQL isn't ever going to show "Using index" in the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: How big is 'huge'?

Comment: @Strawberry about 1.2 billion records totaling about 400 GB.

Comment: That’s fairly huge. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `EXPLAIN` shows "Using index", that means that the index is a ***covering*** index for the query. That is, the query can be satisfied entirely from the index blocks, without requiring any lookups of rows in the underlying table blocks.

Look at your query again. And notice that it's returning the `type` column (the expression in the SELECT list.) That's the whole column. And that whole column is *not* available in the index.

So that index can't be a *covering* index for the query, so MySQL isn't ever going to show 'Using index' in the EXPLAIN output (with that query and that index.)

Since it's not a covering index for the query, MySQL will have to do the lookup to the underlying data page to get the value of the column so it can be returned.

Now as far as whether the index is being used to check the condition `LEFT(type,2) = 'EC'`, we'd need to check the `key_len` in the EXPLAIN output.

We can compare the `key_len` in the EXPLAIN when there is no condition on the `type` column vs when there is a condition. I'd also test with a condition such as `type LIKE 'EC%'`.

I'd compare `key_len` from the EXPLAIN for all of these:

```
 SELECT category, type FROM huge_table WHERE category = 'bar' ; 
 SELECT category, type FROM huge_table WHERE category = 'bar' AND type LIKE 'E%' ; 
 SELECT category, type FROM huge_table WHERE category = 'bar' AND type LIKE 'EC%' ;
 SELECT category, type FROM huge_table WHERE category = 'bar' AND LEFT(type,1) = 'E' ;
 SELECT category, type FROM huge_table WHERE category = 'bar' AND LEFT(type,2) = 'EC' ;
```

If `key_len` is the same (i.e. the length of just the `category` column) in all those cases, then that suggests that MySQL isn't making use the index to check the `LEFT(type,2) =` condition.

And you would be correct. MySQL is visiting the underlying data page before it checks the condition.

But if `key_len` is longer in some of those cases, that suggests that MySQL is checking the condition from the index, before it does the lookup of the row.

---

You might also get an EXPLAIN for a query that doesn't include the `type` column in the SELECT list.

Comment: I suggested testing `type LIKE 'EC%'` in place of `LEFT(type,2) = 'EC'`, but didn't provide a rationale for that. In general, we observe that when a column reference is wrapped inside a function, that prevents MySQL from using a range scan operation with an index on that column. For this reason, in general, we prefer predicates on *bare* columns vs wrapping columns in functions.

Comment: Exactly, I noticed that but didn't understand it at first. `LIKE` seems "clever", at least in modern MySQL versions.

Answer (score 4):

(I agree with Spencer's Answer; this Answer adds more.)

"I am only allowed to create indices" -- If that edict is coming from management, I suggest you warm up your resume.

```
INDEX(category, type)
```

and changing

```
AND LEFT(type,2) = 'EC'
```

to

```
AND type LIKE 'EC%'
```

is the first level of optimization.  Now it will make use of *both* fields in the `INDEX`.  And, assuming that the query is exactly as stated, the index will be "covering", meaning that it does not need to bounce between the index and the data, but can do the entire query in the index BTree.

The second level of optimization is to see whether `type` can be an `ENUM`, which is only 1 byte.  This makes the table and index each several billion bytes smaller.  (This suggest may not be practical, since your "type" is not the typical where there are only a few distinct values, and no "prefixing".)

As for why "using Where" was 15% faster...  *Probably* the following:

- The Optimizer saw the `WHERE` and the `INDEX` and said "hot-digitty; this is a pretty good index; let me use it!".  Then spent a lot of time bouncing between the index and the data.  In the "using Where", it punted on the index and simply scanned the data -- more rows to skip over, but no bouncing back and forth.  (The Optimizer does not have enough *good* statistics to consistently pick between the two.  In your example, the meager stats misled it.)  *Or*, some of the data and/or index BTrees were (or were not) cached at that time.  Run the timings again; you *might* get a different conclusion.  (Typical range: 2x.)

"Using index condition" (aka, ICP = Index Condition Pushdown) also means that the Engine (InnoDB) fetched the row and tested `LEFT(type, 2) = 'EC'`.  In older versions (before ICP), InnoDB fetched the row, but had to send it "up" to the "handler" to perform the test.  The old way slowed things down by ~2x.  But, as you say, the row had to be fetched.  And fetching the row is the most significant part of the inefficiency.

With 1.2B rows, is there room in cache (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`) for all the data and all the index?  Probably not if the data is 400GB.  How much RAM do you have?  Is the buffer_pool about 70% of that setting?

As for "prefix" indexes (`type(2)`) -- they are virtually useless; your code is an example of why.  I tell people to avoid them.

If your `types` are always 4 English digits/letters, then it would cost only 2.4GB to removing `(2)` from the index.  *This* may be the best Answer to your Question.

Another thought...  MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB have "generated/virtual columns".  You could have such for `LEFT(type,2)` and index it.  You would need to change the query to reference that new column.  The column (if not 'persisted') would take no space in the table; the index would use the new column and be no bigger than your existing `(category, type(2))`.  So, if all I say in this paragraph works out, you get the speed you want with no extra disk space consumed!

Comment: Hi Rick thank you for taking the time to amend the accepted answer. I simplified the example and the `type` is actually 12 characters, so I prefer to keep indexing the smallest requirements possible. `LIKE` seems to work perfectly. `LEFT` doesn't. I will look into virtual colums, they seem to be helpful in a myriad of situations.